# Forward aliases to child process

Tags: bash, zsh, alias

I have some aliases which are defined in `/etc/zprofile` (or `/etc/profile` for bash). Also `$PATH` gets manipulated there.

I want to start an interactive shell from a shell which avoids the `$PATH` manipulation. I do this by starting it with the `-f` option. Yet, the aliases which are defined in the parent shell are useful and I'd like to forward them to the child process.

Copy and pasting the aliases which are defined by `/etc/zprofile` once into a text file and sourcing it every time I start another shell is not what I'm looking for as the definitions in `/etc/zprofile` get maintained and may change over time.

Do you have a recommendation how to forward aliases to the second shell?

(My main interest are `zsh` solutions, but I'm curious about `bash` solutions as well)

This is how the situation looks to me

```
# log in with ssh
shell1 > echo "here aliases are the way I want them to be"
shell1 > VARIABLE1=value1 VARIABLE2=value2 PATH=some_paths zsh
shell2 > echo "/etc/zprofile prepended something to PATH, which I don't like"
shell2 > echo "aliases are good"
shell2 > exit
shell1 > VARIABLE1=value1 VARIABLE2=value2 PATH=some_paths zsh -f
shell2 > echo "/etc/zprofile did not prepend something to PATH. This is good!"
shell2 > echo "but all aliases from shell 1 are \"forgotten\""
shell2 > exit
```

Continuing to provide information; the things in `/etc` are more involved than I initially thought:
`/etc/zprofile` contains the following, which I traced down to be what defines my aliases and `$PATH`

```
_src_etc_profile()
{
    #  Make /etc/profile happier, and have possible ~/.zshenv options like
    # NOMATCH ignored.
    #
    emulate -L ksh

    # source profile
    if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
        source /etc/profile
    fi
}
_src_etc_profile

unset -f _src_etc_profile
```

but I missed that `/etc/zshrc` contains

```
_src_etc_profile_d()
{
    #  Make the *.sh things happier, and have possible ~/.zshenv options like
    # NOMATCH ignored.
    emulate -L ksh


    # from bashrc, with zsh fixes
    if [[ ! -o login ]]; then # We're not a login shell
        for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        if [ -r "$i" ]; then
            . $i
        fi
        done
        unset i
    fi
}
_src_etc_profile_d

unset -f _src_etc_profile_d
```

so it's not only `zprofile` which goes through `/etc/profile.d` but also `zshrc`. One of the files in `/etc/profile.d` does then (with comments added by me for how it goes on)

```
if [ -n "$SHLVL" ]; then
    if [ $SHLVL = 1 ]; then
            source /some/group/path/profile
            # calls "source /some/group/path/env"
            # -> see else branch
    else
            source /some/group/path/env
            # calls "source /some/group/path/${SHELL}rc"
            # which then calls
            # "source /my/group/path/group_zshrc"
    fi
else
    echo 'No $SHLVL available, assuming login shell.'
    source /some/group/path/profile
fi
```

and ultimately `/my/group/path/group_zshrc` calls a python program which writes a temporary file in which aliasses and environment variables are defined / manipulated, which is then sourced in the end.

Comment: Running `zsh` does not load `/etc/zprofile`. Did you in fact mean `/etc/zshrc`? Or does `/etc/zshrc` explicitly load `/etc/zprofile`? Can you modify your home directory files? Post the content of `/etc/zprofile`, `/etc/zshrc` and any other relevant file. You don't necessarily have to post the whole, actual content if there are thing there that are private, but **post complete code that reproduces the problem**. With what you've posted now, your question does not make sense since running `zsh` does not load `/etc/zprofile` yet you claim it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't define aliases in `/etc/zprofile` or `~/.zprofile`. These files is only loaded in login shells (“shells” meaning zsh of course). The proper place to define aliases is in `/etc/zshrc` or `~/.zshrc`, which is read by all interactive shells.

To run zsh without loading `/etc/zprofile`, just run `zsh` with no option. The option `-f` tells zsh not to read configuration files at all, but since you want to read your alias definitions, that's not the right option. Since `/etc/zprofile` is only read by a login shell, just *don't* pass the `-l` option (and don't set a zeroth argument that begins with a dash).

Zsh has no option or environment variable to read one extra file on startup. If you want to prepare for that, you can add `eval $ZSH_EXTRA_STARTUP_CODE` to your `.zshrc`.

You can set the `ZDOTDIR` environment variable to make it read all of its user configuration files from a different directory, e.g. `ZDOTDIR=/tmp/foo zsh` reads `/etc/zshenv`, `/tmp/foo/.zshenv`, `/etc/zshrc` and `/tmp/foo/zshrc`. So to export aliases from the current instance to a child instance, you can run something like

```
tmp=$(mktemp -d)
alias -L >$tmp/.zshenv
echo ". ~/.zshenv; unset ZDOTDIR; rm -r ${(q)tmp}" >>$tmp/.zshenv
zsh
```

Comment: I don't have permissions to manipulate `/etc/zprofile`, so as bad as it may be that the definitions are there, I can't move them away from there.

Comment: Also (that was unclear in the original post) the `zsh` I'm starting is supposed to be interactive (as in: I don't want it to execute a script. I want to do "normal shell things" in it: typing, tabbing, opening editors, executing executables, cd'ing)

Answer (score 2):

In `bash`

You can abuse the `--rcfile` option like so:

```
bash --noprofile --rcfile <(alias)
```

But the `--noprofile` is pretty useless without the `-l` option to make it a `login` shell.